# Node.js / Express : download file via ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I am trying to dynamically request a file for download via a GET ajax call. I have the following client-side code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/download/" + "filename",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            complete: function() {
                console.log('Complete');
            },
            success: function() {
                console.log('Success');
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

On the node server I also have the following line (mind you, I have no idea if this is the correct way to do this)

```
app.get('/download/:filename', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.write(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../public/javascripts/main.js", 'utf8'));
});
```

So I want to actually download that javascript file (eventually dynamically). How would I go about doing this correctly? Something tells me I need to be specifying the headers / content type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with Ajax.  A better strategy would be to load the file in an iframe *and* set the headers according to @Bit Destroyer's suggestion.

Comment: Per @apsillers suggestion, if I'm not mistaken, when a browser redirects to a file that has the aforementioned headers, it doesn't actually browse away from the current page, but just opens the save file dialog. With that in mind, the iframe may be superfluous, but don't take my word for it. (ba da dum)

Comment: @Bit, Interesting!  I'll have to check that out and see if it works cross-browser.

Comment: Hey, great advice / idea guys. I'll try it out.

Comment: However, since I am dealing with aa text file, how would I keep the browser from just viewing it? I want to promt the user to download it.

Comment: That's the purpose of the two headers. Add those and it will do what you want it to. The browser will interpret it as a file download and open the save file dialog for you to save without navigating to the page. As @apsillers mentioned though, you should do due diligence though and make sure all of the browsers you are targeting follow this convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return with the content type and disposition set to:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"main.js\"
```

I believe you'll have to redirect to this file though. If I'm not mistaken, you can't force a file download via an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

Is your intent to have the .js file interpreted and applied to the downloading page?

If so you would probably end up using write() to page, no matter how you GET it, and this would not be best-practice.

Instead check out [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). This is a better way to asynchronously and dynamically load scripts, and apply them at runtime.

One difficulty that you would encounter in downloading dynamic .js files, with a manual solution, is dependencies. On .js file dependent on another would result in blind js undefined errors.

Plus, there is a runtime performance optimization gain in converting synchronous included files to asynchronous included files.

[Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) solves for these nicely.

Hope that helps.
All the best!
Clint

Comment: I actually want to download the file. Not include it on the page, or redirect to a text representation of it through the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My Apologies. Watch out for XSRF security vulnerability, especially if JS comes from anywhere other than you. Hope that helps. Nash.